# Error loading preview in Firebase Storage

Tags: react-native, firebase-storage

This is my function put

```
    var metadata = {
      contentType: 'image/png'
    }
    const task = fireStore.ref(fileName).put(uploadUri, metadata)

    try {
      await task
      setUpLoading(false)
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
```

but it didn't work.

Thanks for help.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for it.

```
let newImageUri

try {
  const response = await fetch(imageUrl)
  const blob = await response.blob()

  await firebase.storage().ref().child(fileName).put(blob)
  var ref = firebase.storage().ref().child(fileName).put(blob)

  newImageUri = await ref.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL()
    
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
    
}
```